# PHP to display all MySQL columns without knowing how many there are

Tags: php, mysql

I need some PHP code to display all columns (without referencing how many there are, or their names) in a comma separated, one row per line, format.
I am a novice and have only ever worked with examples where I reference the columns by name:

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from table1");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row["field1"].','.$row["field2"];
}
```

In the above code, can I create a looping echo command based on the number of columns (how do I get this value?) to print all the columns – if I can display the column names in the first row of output, great, but it’s not essential. Or, is there a specific command that will achieve the same result?

I think the answer is a `foreach($row as....)` - but not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Wouldn't echo $row not do the trick ?

Comment: `foreach($row as $r){echo $r.',';}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep you can do a foreach but if you just want to display your values in a CSV style you can do :

```
$firstRow = true;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if ($firstRow) {
        $firstRow = false;
        $columns = array_keys($row);
        // prints all the column names
        echo implode(',', $columns);
    }

    // print all the values
    echo implode(',', $row);
}
```

If you want more control over what you output you can use a foreach :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
        echo $column.' : '.$value."\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to count the `$row` array

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $columns = count($row);
    for($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++)
    {
        echo $row[$i].',';
    }
}
```

Or you can use `foreach()` as @Dagon has pointed out -

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    foreach($row as $column)
    {
        echo $column . ',';
    {
}
```

Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: foreach is sexier, no counting needed :-)

Comment: I'm not feeling very sexy today @Dagon ;-) But I'll add the choice.

Comment: added your suggestion @Dagon and I'm feeling much sexier now ;-)

Comment: that mustache, very sexy ;)